# On the length of a zero dimensional locally complete intersection scheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let, $X$ be a nonsingular closed subscheme in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$(Over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb K$ of characteristic $0$) and $Y$ be a locally complete intersection of $X$.

We know that the length of a closed subscheme $Y$ is defined as dimension of the $\mathbb K$ vector space $\mathcal O_Y(Y)$.

At this point my question is :Is it true that if in the above situation $Y$ is a zero dimensional scheme,then length($Y$) = $|Y|$?

(Here, $|Y|: =$cardinality of $Y$).

I know that if a subscheme is  a finite collection of $d$ distinct point in projective space  then it has degree $d$,but I don't see how to extend it in case of length.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: What do you denote by $|Y|$?

Comment: @Sasha:=cardinality of $Y$.

Comment: Check the example when $Y$ is given by the equations $x^2 = y^2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: @Sasha,In that case,Proj$K[x,y,z]/(x^2,y^2) ={(x,y)/(x^2,y^2)}$ and hence $|Y|=1$,and being a projective variety it also has space of global section the field itself hence have dimension $1$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are wrong; $Y$ has only one closed point, but its local ring is $K[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ (in particular, it is not reduced, hence not a variety).

Comment: @Sasha,could you please elaborate on  what are the other homogeneous prime ideals in $K[x,y,z]$ that contains $(x^2,y^2)$ beside $(x,y)$i.e in other words what are other non -closed points?I realise that$Y$ is not a variety as $(x^2,y^2)$ is not a prime.But then what is its dimension of global sections?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98722/discussion-between-harry-and-sasha).